# source code of GNU Octave function: mldivide

Tags: octave, linear-algebra

Where can I find source code of `mldivide` of GNU Octave? Is it implemented as C++ code or is it m-file? Typing `which mldivide` in GNU Octave command line returns `mldivide is a built-in function`. I searched but I couldn't find the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On octave 3.8.2 at least, you get a bit more information.

```
octave-cli-3.8.2:2> which mldivide 
'mldivide' is a built-in function from the file libinterp/corefcn/data.cc
```

this file can be found on the [octave repository](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/d9c0b08e3da6/libinterp/corefcn/data.cc). That specific function is on [line 6083](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/d9c0b08e3da6/libinterp/corefcn/data.cc#l6083):

```
DEFUN (mldivide, args, ,
       "-*- texinfo -*-\n\
@deftypefn {Built-in Function} {} mldivide (@var{x}, @var{y})\n\
Return the matrix left division of @var{x} and @var{y}.\n\
This function and @w{@tcode{x @xbackslashchar{} y}} are equivalent.\n\
@seealso{mrdivide, ldivide, rdivide}\n\
@end deftypefn")
{
  return binary_op_defun_body (octave_value::op_ldiv, args);
}
```

If you are comfortable going through the headers yourself to track down where magic happens, you should clone the repository to do so. If not, the [octave doxygen docs](https://octave.org/doxygen/) may be helpful but have little more than the method and class names.